# Winning strategy on tic-tac-toe with extra square?

Tags: game-theory, tic-tac-toe

suppose an ordinary game of tic-tac-toe, two players take turn placing a cross or a circle. You win by getting three in a row (horizontally, vertically or diagonally). There is no winning strategy for any of the players.

If you now add an extra square as the picture below. Does any player have a winning strategy?

[image]

I believe there is now winning strategy for any player. However I am having a big problem trying show that no player has a winning strategy... Anyone who can help?

[
I am also supposed to construct a game, with similar rules as tic-tac-toe, with as few squares as possible (does not have to be rectangular), where the player that starts will have a winning strategy... I've managed to get to seven squares, but I am not sure if there is any other possibilities.
]

Comment: Looks like the first player should win.  Start with an $X$ in the bottom row next to the additional square.  Player $2$ must block, presumably by putting an $O$ to the left.then player $1$ claims the middle and everything seems forced from there.  Maybe player $2$ can block by moving into the lower left corner...haven't thought that through.

Comment: No, that fails too.  Player $1$ takes the second square from the left on the bottom, player $2$ must block again, and now $1$ claims the middle.  the point is that the extended row makes it easy for $1$ to force $2$ to block right from the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lulu's comment hits the nail on the head. The first player can force a win. Player 1 puts a $\times$ here:
$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & - & - \\ - & - & \times & -}$$
If the second player does not put a $\Large\circ$ somewhere on the bottom row, then Player 1 plays like so:
$$\matrix{? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? \\ - & \times & \times & -}$$
Now, player 1 has two winning moves, which cannot be blocked. Thus, Player 2 needs to play somewhere on the bottom row.

Let's consider the case where player 2 plays like so:

$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & - & - \\ \Large\circ & - & \times & -}$$

Then player 1 plays:

$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & - & - \\ \Large\circ & \times & \times & -}$$

which forces:

$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & - & - \\ \Large\circ & \times & \times & \Large\circ}$$

Then player 1 plays:

$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & \times & - \\ \Large\circ & \times & \times & \Large\circ}$$

which gives player 1 two possible winning moves, and player 2 will lose after player 1's next turn.

Otherwise, if player 2 did not respond with that move, then the board looks like this:

$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & - & - \\ - & ? & \times & ?}$$

Player 1's next move is
$$\matrix{- & - & - \\ - & \times & - \\ - & ? & \times & ?}$$
which forces
$$\matrix{\Large\circ & - & - \\ - & \times & - \\ - & ? & \times & ?}$$
At this point, player 1's next move is
$$\matrix{\Large\circ & - & - \\ - & \times & \times \\ - & ? & \times & ?}$$
Player 2 has no way to prevent player 1's victory.